# Reduce sql queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 entities:
Project, Keyword, Report
Project has_many keywords
Keyword has_many projects
Project and Report has_many Reports

In keywords index I render a partial to ket the reports for all the keywords in the last 7 days, plus the current day. The problem that I have here, are multiple queries, how I can avoid this?

```
<%=render @keywords%>
```

Partial:

```
<%=keyword.reports.find_today_project_k(Date.today).find_each do |keyword_r|%>
   [<%=keyword_r.pos%>]
<%end%>                  
<%=keyword.reports.find_today_project_k(Date.today - 1.day).find_each do |keyword_r|%>
   [<%=keyword_r.pos%>]
<%end%>
<%=keyword.reports.find_today_project_k(Date.today - 2.day).find_each do |keyword_r|%>
  [<%=keyword_r.pos%>]
<%end%>
<%=keyword.reports.find_today_project_k(Date.today - 3.day).find_each do |keyword_r|%>
  [<%=keyword_r.pos%>]
<%end%>
```

Controller: keyword/index

```
@keywords = project.keywords.page(params[:page])
```

Thank you

Comment: What does `find_today_project_k` look like?

Comment: Its a scope `->(date) { where("DATE(created_at) = ?", date)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you need the records from 3 days back until today. Why don't you add a scope that builds this WHERE clause, in one query? You then just have to loop through the query result's keywords to display them appropriately instead of firing up 4 queries.

`scope :latest, ->(date){ where("DATE(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?", date - 3.days, date) }`